# Connect Oracle Forms builder to Oracle XE database, both 10G

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-xe

I have created the default database in Oracle XE (The hr user and schema)

I have Oracle developer suite - Dev10G,  installed on my computer.

When I load Forms builder and use the "Connect" screen, it asks me for Username, password and database.

I know that the username and password is hr and hr, but I cant seem to connect.

I believe that i need to edit the tnsnames.ora file in my oracle XE install, but I'm not sure if I'm correct.

Is this what I need to do and if so can anybody tell me what exactly I need to paste in here.

Comment: What database (service name) are you using? The default for xe (assuming you didn't change it from the default) is `orcl`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure i need to add a connect string to the tnsnames.ora file before i can do that though. My problem is I dont know what form that connection string should take

Comment: If XE is installed, its tnsnames.ora should be fine already. You may need to copy it into the Oracle home used by developer suite. Look for the "...network/admin" folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your DevSuiteHome environment to look at your OracleXE tnsnames.ora, or copy the tns entry from the OracleXE environment to the DevSuiteHome one...  In my environments, I just set the TNS_ADMIN registry key in DevSuiteHome to point to the OracleXE TNS_ADMIN directory...

Answer (score 0):

on windows 7 run  regedit and go to `ORACLE  > KEY_DevSuiteHome1` and look for TNS_ADMIN and change the value of it  to `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\NETWORK\ADMIN` 
which contains the file tnsnames.ora